# jQuery parsing raw HTML, and hasOwnProperty on Firefox

Tags: jquery

I load up some HTML using `$.get` or `$.ajax`. In the debugger for both Chrome and Firefox i can see the html has been loaded properly:

**> data**

```
"<html><head><title></title></head><body>
<div id="topdiv" style="display:none;width:880px; height:600px;"></div>
</body</html>"
```

So it's a string of HTML. Great. Next I try to use jQuery to parse it:

`$doc = $(data);`

**> $doc**

```
[<TextNode textContent="\n\n">, 
title, 
<TextNode textContent="\n\n\n">, 
div#topdiv, 
<TextNode textContent="\n \n">]
```

Whoah, what? Where did `html`, `head`, `body` go? OK, well anyway, all I care about is the div

`$div = $data.find('div');`

**> $div**

`[]`

Huh??

OK. The div is empty. Upon further experimentation, I realize that jQuery basically ignores any top-level tags. Then it doesn't actually let you select any 2nd level tags, and so if there is a div nested inside the outer div, that WILL be selected. But... what??

Seems jQuery kind of chokes on those "TextNode" elements, that, curiously, it created itself (instead of html, body). So I wrote some code to get around this by looping through the elements, and extracting the non-text nodes directly:

```
function getNodes($doc) {
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < $doc.length; i++) {
        if ($doc[i].hasOwnProperty("tagName")) {
            result.push($doc[i]);
        }
    }
    return $(result);
}
```

Worked great! On Chrome.

Tried it in Firefox, and nothing works again.

Turns out that not every object in Firefox has a `hasOwnProperty` function. WHAT?? Ok. So rewrite to this:

`typeof($tempHtml[i].tagName) !== 'undefined'`

Finally, works in Firefox too.

Wow. Am I just being stupid? Why is so much post processing needed just to turn a string of HTML into a jQuery object? I feel like I must be missing something obvious. Is there a way to do this that does not involve such mayhem?

All I am trying to do is load up some HTML and turn it into a jQuery object. Yet it seems to be an increasingly baffling ordeal. Am I just doing something fundamentally wrong? Why is this so complicated?

Comment: I like how you type sounds and talk to yourself.

Comment: It's very lonely in the dungeon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) - it addresses this issue.

When you have a HTML string that contains `<html>`, `<head>`, or `<body>` elements, and you do this:

```
$(str)
```

then those elements will be ignored. Only elements that can be put inside a DIV are valid and will be added to the resulting jQuery instance object.

---

```
$div = $data.find('div');
```

This will result in an empty jQuery object because find() searches the descendants of the current set of elements (which is one TITLE element and one DIV element in your case - and those two elements don't have descendant DIV elements).

---

In order to remove the Text Node objects from your jQuery object, I recommend this approach:

```
$data.filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 1; });
```

---

To get the DIV element, I recommend this approach:

```
$('<div>').html(str).find('div');
```

where `str` is your HTML string.

---

Alternative approach:

```
$(str).filter('div');
```

Answer (score 1):

### A working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/FuNhF/

As for why it's not working: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6380

As for why you cannot find a child element div is because after the html and body tags are stripped you end up with a title and a div, two different un-nested elements.

```
    var data = $('<title></title><div id="topdiv" style="display:none;width:880px; height:600px;"></div>');
    console.log(data[0]); //Title
    console.log(data[1]); //Div
```

As opposed to:

```
var data = $('<div><div id="topdiv" style="display:none;width:880px; height:600px;"></div></div>');

console.log(data);
```

Where the console output is the main div with topdiv nested inside it.

**You should also make sure the HTML you pass in is valid, as otherwise you will have "unexpected" results, example: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/6wKk3/**

Comment: That explains why those elements are missing, by why can't jQuery properly select the div after that? What is the usual way people deal with this most basic of tasks?

Comment: Because it returns an array of 2 objects, the title and the div. See: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/gT6ya/

Comment: Updated the question with some extra info, hopefully it'll make more sense now.

Comment: It returns an array of 5 objects, though only 2 are DOM objects. But trying to select one of those 2 DOM objects does not work. Hence the need to iterate through the array. I don't understand why jquery would return something in a jQuery object that it is consequently unable to deal with.

Comment: I don't see how it returns an array of 5 objects, could you provide an example on JSFiddle?

Comment: @Peeter - first I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gT6ya/11/ notice that `console.log($(data).find('div'));` returns an empty array. That seems very odd to me.

Comment: @jamietre You're using the wrong method. You have to use filter(), not find().

Answer (score 1):

One quick addition to @Sime's excellent answer. If you're not chaining your commands you need to set $data to the results of the filter. The filter function doesn't apply to the original collection.

```
$data = $data.filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 1; });
// do other stuff with your properly filtered $data collection
```