# Solution to jQuery.get() returning null on Localhost?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues getting jQuery to work correctly while testing on Localhost.

The function that's giving me trouble:

```
function poll() {
        $.get(location.href, function(data) {
            var x = $('#datadump', data);
            alert(x.html());
        });
    }
```

Where `location.href = http://localhost/polltest.php`

The alert merely returns `null` instead of a random number produced by PHP's `rand` function. The source of localhost/polltest.php is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function poll() {
            $.get(location.href, function(data) {
                var x = $('#datadump', data);
                alert(x.html());
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="poll();">
    <div id="datadump">
        <?php
            $val = rand(0, 100);
            echo $val;
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help regarding a way for this to work would be wonderful and appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to add the result of $.get() to `<div id="datadump"> </div>` ?

Comment: At this point I'm only trying to get the innerHTML of #datadump (the output of `rand(0, 100);` in php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple ways to achieve the value of the div with id datadump.

One of the ways being

```
   function poll() {
        $.get(location.href, function(data) {
            x = $(data).filter('#datadump');
            console.log(x);
        });
    }
```

The reason it is failing for you:

When you have an HTML string which contains `<html>, <head>, <body>` tags, and you try to do

```
$(string)
```

those elements will be ignored. Only those elements which can be put inside a div are valid. Read it in the [jQuery documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM
>   that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, we use
>   the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert
>   it into the current document. During this process, some browsers
>   filter out certain elements such as `<html>, <title>, or <head>`
>   elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative
>   of the original string passed.

This issue has been discussed in detail on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642602/410367

Comment: Thanks! This worked. However, I don't believe your reason for failure is correct, as the method I originally tried _does_ work on sites **other** than localhost.

Comment: @AlexL I would like to see it happening elsewhere in that case. I've also added a link to related SO discussion in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way,

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var x = $('#ads');
        alert(x.html());

         $.get(location.href, function (data) {
            var x = $('#ads', data);
            alert(data);
            alert(x.html());
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="datadump">
    <?php
        $val = rand(0, 100);
        echo $val;
    ?>
  </div>
</body>
```

Update: I have changed the script little bit similar to your original post. It works fine for me.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of using $.get(), since that only grabs the innerHTML of #datadump that was originally loaded.